# VBScript Issue - Cannot find correct syntax for Detection Clause

Tags: vbscript, sccm

Excuse me for this - there's an issue with this code - it's from

https://www.alexandreviot.net/2014/10/03/configmgr-2012-application-detection-method-for-software-update/#comment-40712

I don't normally use VB i use PS and have tried various things editing line 7 of this code which is:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &amp;strComputer &amp; "\root\cimv2")
```

With no success. Can anyone help here? This might be quite easy for someone - this would help me use vb as a detection clause for older hardware which doesn't run the windows management framework/powershell.

```
'Returns if Windows KB2506143 installed
    Option Explicit
    Dim objWMI, strComputer
    strComputer = "."

    'Run the query
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &amp;strComputer &amp; "\root\cimv2")

    Dim listPatches
    Dim patch
    Set listPatches = objWMI.ExecQuery ("Select * from win32_QuickFixEngineering where HotFixID like 'KB960568'")
    For Each patch in listPatches
    Wscript.echo "Update installed"
    Next
    WScript.Quit


    C:\Users\royston\AppData\Local\Adersoft\VbsEdit\Temp\BCAWFOZT.vbs(7, 76) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'


    ***** script completed - exit code: 1 *****
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have html entities included in the code. `&amp;` = `&` , so you should use `... & strComputer & ...` , being `&`  the standard concatenation operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably just a problem with pasting code into whatever that site uses for interpreting it. It should say

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

but as this is really somewhat of a pet peeve of mine I wanna add that the whole concept of using strComputer when not used as a variable is really useless.
I know it is done in every example on the web but if you want to run wmi locally and not remotely just use

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
```

and drop the `strComputer = "."` line. There is really no need to make scripts harder to read when the variable is used like a constant.

Comment: Thank you Syberdoor for bringing up the extraneous use of a strComputer variable!  That's also a pet peeve of mine.